# Problem while getting device information in Huawei QuickApp

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am developing a quick app and I am having a problem while calling method below.

```
device.getInfo()
```

I am trying to obtain my phone's height from the information provided but it always returns **0**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether the asynchronous mode is used when the **device.getInfo()** method is invoked in the **onCreate()** method in the **app.ux** file. If so, delete the asynchronous mode.

After the asynchronous mode is deleted, if the height is still 0, the **device.getInfo()** method **may be invoked before the data is ready**. It usually takes around **50-100 ms** for the data to be ready.